# How to break a field in CR on a comma for a name

Tags: crystal-reports

What would be an appropriate formula to break a field separated by a comma.
This is a name field so the number of characters vary.

Example.
Field is Jones, Mike

What is the formula to get just jones to populate and also need one to show mike as the result?

Comment: The fact that you use the actual name of the function you need in the question, `split()`, tells me that you didn't bother to Google this first or look in the Crystal Report help file. Please try to solve the problem _first_ and come back and post if you run into trouble.

Comment: I did search multiple websites, checked the help files.  Perhaps I just could not word it correctly and 'split' way not the appropriate tag.  I will remove this tag. I am in need something to determine the comma position. Then the string function right or left to parse out the name

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the field's value is *always* `first, last` (note the space) then you'd need two formula fields:

```
//{@FirstName}
Split({Table.Field}, ", ")[2]

//{@LastName}
Split({Table.Field}, ", ")[1]
```